# How to put sign_up form on the home page without Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came with [How to display a custom sign_in form anywhere in your app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app), that uses Devise to place any form anywhere.

But we don't want to use Devise.

I have tried using:

```
<%= render 'sessions/new',  :locals => {:session => Session.new} %>
```

And in the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
```

But it didn't work.

I've also tried load the session, it did not work too.

Does someone have any hint?

```
before_filter :load_categories
  protected

  def load_categories
    @sessions = Session.new
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside routes.rb

```
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
```

inside app/controllers/session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # just put empty here
    # rails will automatically render views/sessions/new.html.erb
    # makesure you have this file  
  end

  # I put create and delete session in case you need it later
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        login user
        flash[:success] = "Anda berhasil login"
        redirect_to yours_path
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'sorry cannot login'
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "Log out"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

inside views/sessions/new.html.erb (I put sample for login page so you can check)

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
<h2>Please sign in</h2>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username, "User name", class: "sr-only" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "User name" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password, class: "sr-only" %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
  </p>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
  <h4>
    <%= link_to "Reset Password?", new_password_reset_path %>
  </h4>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i mean put the form in the home page and not create the session logic.

Comment: how about if inside your homepage controller method call render the sample form that I created above with this command <%= render 'sessions/new' %>

Comment: well worked, strange. did not worked before. thank you widjajayd.
something that i was missing.